# Remove a file from git

Tags: windows, git

How can I remove a file from git history on Windows? I mean to remove it completely since the file contains sensitive data and has been pushed to a remote server unintentionally.

Is there any easy built-in git tool / command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the git's help: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

> Remove sensitive data From time to time users accidentally commit data
>   like passwords or keys into a git repo. While you can use git rm to
>   remove the file, it will still be in the repo's history. Fortunately,
>   git makes it fairly simple to remove the file from the entire repo
>   history.